# saving nested mongoose object arrays

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema config:

```
childSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    filePath: String,
    color: String
})
parentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    date: String,
    files: [childSchema]
})
grandparentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    byDate: [parentSchema]
})
```

Saving an updated entry of parentSchema works fine using

```
model.markModified('byDate')
model.save()
```

but it does not work with the childSchema.

I have also tried it with the MongooseArray.set() method, without success.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apperantly my mistake was not in saving but in retrieving:

changing data.byDate to data[0].byDate in my find callback saved the day.

Sorry for asking prematurely. This was a trivial error indeed